# How do I customize the comment reply link?

Tags: 7, comments, navigation

I'm trying to customize the comment reply link to direct the user to the comment submission form on the same page. I've tried:

```
<?php 
$content['links']['#links']['comment-reply']['href'] = '#edit-comment-body-und-0-value';
?>
```

in my comment.tpl.php, but no luck. Also I need to add a JavaScript `onclick` to make the comment body in focus and add the user name of the user being replied to.

What should I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at the code of the [AJAX comments module](http://drupal.org/project/ajax_comments). It does simmilar things. There's a good chance that you can learn from theire code.

Comment: Thanks, I just ended up using the ajax comments module, its exactly what I needed.